# Cannot build libtess.so in tess-two

Tags: android, android-ndk, tesseract, tess-two

Basically when I run ndk-build command in the tess-two folder which I have extracted after downloading, the following error occurs -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYQvr.png

my ndk version is android-ndk-r10c

Due to this libtess.so is not being created in the arm64-v8a folder.

If someone can, then please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just downloaded android-ndk-r12b and that seemed to have solve the problem for me. The libtess.so is now being created in the arm64-v8a folder.